# How can I pass parameters to a python script when running it with a bash script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to make an application that will work from the command line.  For instance `application -h`.  So I put a bash script in my `/usr/local/bin/` that does `cd /path/to/application`  Then on the next line `./Main.py`.  But if I execute the command it it doesn't receive the `-h`.  However if I do an alias in my `.bashrc` with the same commands it works just fine. How could I change the bash script to work with parameters? And why does the alias work but not the script?

Comment: Examples and contents of the bash script would help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because shell script has no way of knowing that you want to pass arguments to your Python script. Use

```
./Main.py "$@"
```

Also don't use `cd`. It's redundant.  Just use full path to ./Main.py , or even better avoid having a wrapper script altogether, unless necessary. Just put ./Main.py into one of the directories that are part of your $PATH variable and call your Python script directly.

The main point is that what you're trying to do is probably wrong and unnecessary, and there are better ways to do it